# How to remove double drive listing in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

In Windows 10, whenever I insert a USB or External HDD, it gives me two listings for it in the Explorer pane:

[image: Screenshot of Explorer Pane]

Is there any way I can remove the second listing? Preferably the standalone one, as I'm used to it being under "This PC", muscle memory y'know.

Comment: Well I guess they still haven't fixed it from the [early days](http://www.tenforums.com/installation-setup/2819-file-explorer-shows-extenal-usb-volumes-twice.html). If you right click either, is there no remove option?

Comment: @MC10 Unfortunately no, only Format and Eject (relating to the drive, that is)

Answer (score 3):

PART 5: Remove Removable Drive Icon from Navigation Pane of This PC

1. Open Registry Editor and go to following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders

2. Under "DelegateFolders" key, you'll find {F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83} key.
3. Now delete the {F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83} key and it'll immediately remove the double removable drive icon from This PC Navigation Pane.

If you want to restore removable drive icon, create a new key under DelegateFolders key and set its name to {F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83} again.

NOTE: If you are using 64-bit edition of Windows 10, you may notice that the drive icon is still present in "Browse" dialog box such as Save, Save as or Open in some 3rd party 32-bit programs. To remove the duplicate drive icon from there, you'll need to perform the same steps in following key as well:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders

Under "DelegateFolders" key, delete {F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83} key.

**OR:**
create a .reg file , with this content: (after saving, rightclick the .reg file and select 'merge')

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.tenforums.com
:: Tutorial: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4675-drives-navigation-pane-add-remove-windows-10-a.html


[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}]
```

Answer (score -2):

I am sure that in this long time, a year, you did find the solution. Anyway, for those which by searching will find this question unanswered, here's the answer. There is a web page at the address http://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-remove-onedrive-quick-access-homegroup-and-network-icons-from-navigation-pane-of-this-pc/ which provide detailed instructions how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: it's too long and contains formatting and pictures. The information is also very accessible with search engines...

Comment: So summarise it.